# Verifying an equation that contains roots of unity

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\zeta_n$ denote the $n$th root of unity. We know that:

$$X^{n}-1 = (X-1) \cdot (X-\zeta_n) \cdot (X-\zeta_n^2) \cdot \ldots \cdot (X-\zeta_n^{n-1}).$$

I wanted to "verify" this formula by hand for the case $n=2$, but I do not manage it. $(X-1)\cdot(X-\zeta_2)$ should equal $X^2-1$, but I only get:

$$(X-1)\cdot(X-\zeta_2) = X^2-\zeta_2 X - X + \zeta_2.$$

Am I doing something wrong? Or can I somehow proceed from here?

Comment: $\zeta_2 = -1$. BTW, there is a sign error in the constant term in your last expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @achills hui has noted $\zeta_2=-1$. Plugging that into your expression gives $X^2-1$